# outlook raw query for emails having a category and flagged as important?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, search, microsoft-outlook-2016

I'm confused how create a smart folder in outlook that utilizes a raw query for emails having a category and flagged as important

tried something like `category:yes` to begin, but i'm not seeing any emails with categories show up.

Comment: is your 'search in' set to the correct location?

Comment: @Ack yes, i’m searching the correct location

Comment: It is suggested to use Outlook Search Folder: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-search-folders-to-find-messages-or-other-outlook-items-c1807038-01e4-475e-8869-0ccab0a56dc5

Comment: @Aidan yes, i’m currently using the smart search folders

Answer (score 0):

New Search Folder

Select a Search Folder = Create a custom Search Folder (under Custom group at the bottom of the list)

Customize Search Folder > click Choose... button

Select Criteria button

Search Folder Criteria > Advanced tab

[image]

Field=categories (can be found under Frequently used)

Conditor=is empty

Comment: doesn't work for me :(

I did raw query NOT category: [ ] and I'm not seeing any emails show up

Comment: I've updated the answer, please try. I've tested and it worked for me.

Comment: thank you for editing the answer, but i’m looking for a raw query so I can add Boolean logic. I was already familiar with filtering on categories through the UI filters in outlook. it really seems I can’t achieve my primary question through a raw query right?

Comment: My apologies, I overlooked that important part of the question. That's outside my area and I don't think I can be any help with that

Comment: ok, thank you for trying :)